# SSH disconnects when screen locked with vlock

Tags: ssh, tmux, putty, screen-lock

I'm using tmux + PuTTY to get all the UNIX goodness I need when using Windows. I have the following settings in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g lock-command vlock
set-option -g lock-after-time 1800
```

As expected, after 30 minutes, my screen goes to this:

```
This TTY is now locked.  
Please press [ENTER] to unlock.
```

And then it all goes wrong... after awhile PuTTY gives me the follow error: `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`

[image]

Any thoughts on why I'm getting disconnected from SSH?

Comment: How long is "awhile"?  Does it happen if you don't use vlock?  I'm just guessing that the connection is timing out somehow.  Maybe try some of the suggestions here: http://staff.ask.sydney.edu.au/app/answers/detail/a_id/614/~/how-do-i-configure-my-putty-client-to-not-time-out-due-to-inactivity%3F

Comment: Good call there @depquid, that seemed to do the trick. Would you like to write up an answer since you pointed me in the right direction?

Comment: It'd be better if you wrote up exactly what fixed the problem for you; all I did was 2 minutes of Google and pasted a link. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the [link](http://staff.ask.sydney.edu.au/app/answers/detail/a_id/614/~/how-do-i-configure-my-putty-client-to-not-time-out-due-to-inactivity) provided by [@depquid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34210/depquid), changing connection timeout settings in PuTTY did the trick.

[image: PuTTY settings screenshot]

1. Go to the `Connection` section of PuTTY's configuration screen
2. Check `Enable TCP keepalives (SO_KEEPALIVE option)`
3. In the `Sending of null packets to keep session active`, change the value for `Seconds between keepalives` to something other than zero. I had originally tried 1800 (30 minutes), but that ended up being too high. I'm doing 60 seconds now which might be overkill, but it's done the trick for me.